# PHP / Javascript variable passing -- unexpected results

Tags: javascript, php

I am calling a php page (using PHP7.0) from javascript (on Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99).  Reading around the web, I used a code example.  Passing a json string through PUT to php is supposed to deliver a $_POST variable that is a map.

`{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"}` becomes

```
$_POST = [  "a" => "A", "b" => "B", "c"=>"C" ]
```

However, in my code below, javascript passed instead

```
$_POST = [ "{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"}" : "" ]
```

This is bizarre.  If not a map, I would have expected a String

Did I do something wrong?  This is a little nerve-wracking to think the code is unreliable for production.  Or perhaps there is a better approach?

javascript:

```
function testeroo(){

    json_ = '{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"}'

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: './test.php',
        data: json_,
        success: function (obj) {
            alert(obj);  
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR testeroo");
        }
    });

}
```

test.php confirms this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $zeroKey = $key;  
    //only one key, so $zeroKey is only key
}
$j = json_decode($zeroKey);
            //$j is the expected map
```

Answer (score 4):

your `json_` is string,   remove  `''`

```
 json_ = {"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"}
```

Answer (score 0):

two solutions:

**1**

> as suggested by the other user:

remove  `''` from your json string

**2**

> if you want to use a string you must also use the function
>   [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Example

```
  var json_= '{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"}';
    json_= JSON.parse(json_);
```